# One of my blender files is not opening

Tags: error

I have a file that opened before on this version of blender (blender 2.81a) but now it is not opening and it is even saying that a graphic card and driver with support for openGL 3.3 or higher is required.

[image]

This is strange, because I have a previously saved version of that file that opens and renders well in Blender. Even others blend files that I have, open in blender and render in it without any issue. I am confused regarding this problem.

Comment: Please create a report on the official bug tracker through *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender. Follow the submission template (replace text in square brackets with the actual information) and provide system information, Blender version, a concise and precise description of the issue, step by step instructions to reproduce it and the .blend file that demonstrates the problem.